# How to integrate constants and functions in React Component class?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, react-component

Let's take the AppBar code from Material-UI:
https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#app-bar-with-a-primary-search-field

There is a "renderMobileMenu". I want to integrate it. The problem is that the sample code uses "function" whereas mine is a React Component class. I need guidance on how to integrate that renderMobileMenu (and relevant) piece of code in a React Component class.
I am also using React Redux.

```
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {wbToggle: wbToggle, vidToggle: vidToggle, fileToggle: fileToggle}
)(Utilitybar);
```

I have tried but it always gives error that I am breaking laws of hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check the v3 docs to see how it's used in the old fashioned way.

https://v3.material-ui.com/demos/app-bar/#app-bar

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. It's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your class name is "Utilitybar". As you need to use the piece of code and functionality from the sample, you can achieve it in two ways,

1. Simply copy the function you required and paste it outside the class with required dependent functions and packages and call it - (not recommended approach and dirty way)
2. Create one stateless component(based on your need state-full / stateless) with the functions you need to add it in existing class, in the newly created stateless component import the required functions and packages. Once its done your stateless component is ready to serve then go ahead and import in your Utilitybar and use it.

Refer the below example,

You need to create a separate stateless component

```
<path>/MobileMenu.js

/*import the dependency packages, files you are referring in your sample function*/
import React from 'react';
import { fade, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar'; 
...
...
....

export const RenderMobileMenu = ({
}) => {
  /*copied the dependent functions to render - renderMobileMenu*/
  const [mobileMoreAnchorEl, setMobileMoreAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const isMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const isMobileMenuOpen = Boolean(mobileMoreAnchorEl);
  const mobileMenuId = 'primary-search-account-menu-mobile';
  
  function handleMobileMenuClose() {
    setMobileMoreAnchorEl(null);
  }
  
  function handleMenuClose() {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    handleMobileMenuClose();
  }
  
  /*copied the code under renderMobileMenu*/
  return (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={mobileMoreAnchorEl}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      id={mobileMenuId}
      keepMounted
      transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      open={isMobileMenuOpen}
      onClose={handleMobileMenuClose}
    >
      <MenuItem>
        <IconButton aria-label="Show 4 new mails" color="inherit">
          <Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary">
            <MailIcon />
          </Badge>
        </IconButton>
        <p>Messages</p>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>
        <IconButton aria-label="Show 11 new notifications" color="inherit">
          <Badge badgeContent={11} color="secondary">
            <NotificationsIcon />
          </Badge>
        </IconButton>
        <p>Notifications</p>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}>
        <IconButton
          aria-label="Account of current user"
          aria-controls="primary-search-account-menu"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          color="inherit"
        >
          <AccountCircle />
        </IconButton>
        <p>Profile</p>
      </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    )
}
```

Now RenderMobileMenu is ready to serve for Utilitybar.js.

Simply  go ahead and import this RenderMobileMenu.js file in your Utilitybar.js and use it under render( return() ) method.

Happy coding!!

Comment: Your code has helped my concepts. I am a beginner at React JS. This particular piece helped me in another part of my project. THANKS! :D